# PhpStorm Menu and Toolbar arrangement

Tags: menu, phpstorm, toolbar

I want 'Current Line', 'Line Separator' and 'Git Branch' from the Status bar (bottom) moved to the Navigation Bar (top). But I can't find anything in the 'Menus and Toolbars' settings.

My end goal is to have the Navigation Bar plus the additional fields in the same line. And complete hide all other icons I don't need in the status bar.

I am currently on the 2018.2.4 build.

[image: PhpStorm Status Menu]

Comment: You cannot do that.

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne. Good to know, I was searching like a madman...